# Credit card validation - returning values that aren't hard coded

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, luhn

How do I compute the answer so that the answer is not a hard-coded solution? Like if I wanted to put in another credit card number how can I return the result of that new credit card? Also how can I create one x list rather then the way I have it now with the values split up by 2?

Also here is the original question for reference:

> Credit card numbers are validated using Luhn’s formula 3. Implement a program that takes a credit card numbers as a multidimensional array (you may assume it consists of exactly  of 16 columns), and returns a list with values *Valid* if it is a valid card number, and *Invalid* otherwise.
>
> One way to perform the validity test is as follows:
>   1.  From the rightmost digit, which is the check digit, moving left, double the value of every second digit; if the product of this doubling operation is greater than 9 (e.g., 8  2 = 16), then sum the digits of the products (e.g.,16: 1 + 6 = 7, 18: 1 + 8 = 9).
>   2.  Take the sum of all the digits.
>   3.  If the total is divisible by 10, then the number is valid according to the Luhn formula; else it is not valid.
>
> Note: You can maniplulate card numbers either as strings (using indexing and slicing to extract digits, etc) or as integers (using integer division and remainder to manipulate digits).

My script:

```
    import numpy as py

    x = [[7,1],[6,3],[4,5],[6,2],[7,8],[3,4],[6,8],[3,9]] #credit card numbers
    x2 = np.array(x)
    evryothernum = x2[:,1]       #returns every other number / every seconds digit
    evryothernum2 = np.multiply(evryothernum,2)
    sumdigits = []

    def card_validate(x):
        evryothernum = x2[:,1]        #valid
        evryothernum2 = np.multiply(evryothernum,2) #multiplys         evryothernum by 2
        b=np.sort(evryothernum2, axis = None) #sorts the evryothernum2 array in order
        b2 = np.array(b)
        b3 = b2[4:8] #shows the highest values aka greater than 9 
        b3
        b3 = [1,7,7,9]
        newb3 = np.sum(b3)
        newx2 = np.sum(x2[:,0])
        total = np.sum(newb3+newx2)
        if ( (total % 10) == 0 ):
            print "Valid"
        else:
            print "Invalid"
        return card_validate()
```

*Is there an easier way then to do this without Numpy?*

Comment: You are asking several questions. Split it and focus on each with the relevant lines of code. Your full solution isn't needed for small parts

Comment: Note also that numpy is massive overkill for implementing Luhn's.

Comment: is there an easier way then to do this without numpy?

Comment: This is a fun toy project in Haskell. [See my solutions here](https://repl.it/repls/DamagedGiganticAsiandamselfly)

Answer (score 0):

**The following can be used to implement the logic without using numpy**

```
a=[[4,0,1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,1,8,8,1],[4,0,1,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,1,8,8,2]] #array of credit card numbers
def validate(creditcard_numbers,tmp):
    even_index=-1

    for j in range(0,16): 
        sum_val=0
        if even_index%2 ==0:  #index calculation for even indices
            val=creditcard_numbers[even_index]*2 
            if val>9:   # add the digits if the value got after multiplying by 2 is two digit number
                while val !=0:
                    rem=val%10
                    val=val/10
                    sum_val=sum_val+rem

                tmp[even_index]=sum_val  #append the temporary list with the new values which is got by adding the digits if the result of multiplying by 2 is a 2 digit number

            else:
                tmp[even_index]=val

        else:
            tmp[even_index]=creditcard_numbers[even_index]
        even_index=even_index-1

    total=0
    for i in tmp:
        total=total+i
    if total%10 == 0:
        return "valid"
    else:
        return "invalid"


for creditcard_numbers in a:
    print creditcard_numbers
    tmp=[0]*len(creditcard_numbers) #temporary list with zeros's 
    result=validate(creditcard_numbers,tmp)
    print result
```

**OUTPUT :
[4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 8, 8, 1]

valid

[4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 8, 8, 2]

invalid
**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways.  The first is a straight port to Python of the pseudo-code on the "Luhn algorithm" Wikipedia page ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm)).  The second uses a lookup table to with the pre-computed doubled value of every other digit:

```
def checkLuhn(purportedCC):
     sm = 0
     nDigits = len(purportedCC)
     parity = nDigits % 2
     for i in range(nDigits):
         digit = int(purportedCC[i])
         if i % 2 == parity:
             digit = digit * 2
             if digit > 9:
                 digit = digit - 9
         sm = sm + digit
     return (sm % 10) == 0

def check(s):
    lookup = [0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9]
    digits = [int(c) for c in reversed(s)] # count odd/even from the right
    odd = digits[::2]
    even = digits[1::2]
    total = sum(odd) + sum(lookup[c] for c in even)
    return total % 10 == 0

cards = '1111222233334444','1111222233334445','01111222233334444'

for card in cards:
    print(card,check(card))
    print(card,checkLuhn(card))
```

Output (note if done correctly leading zeros don't affect the validation):

```
1111222233334444 True
1111222233334444 True
1111222233334445 False
1111222233334445 False
01111222233334444 True
01111222233334444 True
```